# Anchor revisited hovering in xhtml

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Here is my code on link. Whenever I visit a  link, I want my link to be white in color whenever I come back to the page and  *hover over it.* For some reason, it changes to black whenever I hover over it.

```
a:link {    
   font-size: 18px;                              
   background-color: none;
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
   background-color: #1E425A;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding-left: 3px;
   padding-right: 3px;
}
a:visited {
   background-color: none;
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS rulesets with equal specificity are applied *in order*.

If you want your `:hover` rules to override your `:visited` rules, then move your `:hover` ruleset *after* your `:visited` ruleset.

Answer (score 0):

This should override your `visited` rule

```
a:link{
font-size: 18px;                              
background-color:none;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited{
background-color:none;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
background-color: #1E425A;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
}
a:active{
background-color: blue;
}
```